# Find average of one property from object grouped by another property

Tags: powershell

Below is my CSV file with the data

```
SummaryMonth    OSType  AVERAGE_of_Availability
10/7/2019 10:30 Unix    100
10/7/2019 10:30 Network 99.95039683
10/7/2019 10:30 Unix    100
10/7/2019 10:30 Unix    99.8015873
10/7/2019 10:30 Network 100
10/7/2019 10:30 Network 100
10/7/2019 10:30 Windows 99.95037221
10/7/2019 10:30 Network 100
10/7/2019 10:30 Unix    100
10/7/2019 10:30 Windows 100
10/7/2019 10:30 storage 100
```

I have used the `Group-Object` and grouped the data based on `OSType`

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                           
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                           
1720 Unix                      {@{SummaryMonth=10/7/2019 10:30:00 AM; DNSName=; OSType=Unix; NodeName=test01.test.local; IP_Address=xx.xx.xx.xx; AVERAG...
297 Network                   {@{SummaryMonth=10/7/2019 10:30:00 AM; DNSName=; OSType=Network; NodeName=TEST; IP_Address=xx.xx.xx.xx; AVERAGE_of_Ava...
799 Windows                   {@{SummaryMonth=10/7/2019 10:30:00 AM; DNSName=; OSType=Windows; NodeName=test; IP_Address=xx.xx.xx.xx; AVERAGE_of_Av...
39 storage                   {@{SummaryMonth=10/7/2019 10:30:00 AM; DNSName=test.com; OSType=storage; NodeName=test...
```

I got the output as above.

I need to find the average of `AVERAGE_of_Availability` from each OS type from this.

For example for Unix the count is 1720, so sum of all the 1720 records and then find the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Measure-Object -Average` like this:

```bsh
# Constructing test data
# In your case you probably use Import-CSV instead
# If Import-CSV was used, no need to use ConvertFrom-CSV
$data = @"
SummaryMonth;OSType;AVERAGE_of_Availability
10/7/2019 10:30;Unix;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Network;99.95039683
10/7/2019 10:30;Unix;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Unix;99.8015873
10/7/2019 10:30;Network;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Network;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Windows;99.95037221
10/7/2019 10:30;Network;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Unix;100
10/7/2019 10:30;Windows;100
10/7/2019 10:30;storage;100
"@ | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter ';'

# Grouping data
$grouppedData = $data | Group-Object OSType

# Getting desired data
$result = $grouppedData | Select-Object Name,@{name="Avg";e={($_.Group.AVERAGE_of_Availability | Measure-Object -Average).Average}}

# Output the result
$result
```

Output will be:

```bsh
Name              Avg
----              ---
Unix     99.950396825
Network 99.9875992075
Windows  99.975186105
storage           100
```

### Explanation:

In your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) you have to use calculated property to *construct* the desired value in (in your case average value of `AVERAGE_of_Availability`). As [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6) returns the value with the format like

```bsh
Count    : 1
Average  : 100
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

what you have to do is to access only `Average` property of that object. You can do this by using the dot-notation: `($object | Measure-Object -Average).Average`. In your case, instead of `$object` you put the array of `AVERAGE_of_Availability` values for proper `OSType`.

### References:

More about calculated property (just one example article) can be found [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Import-Csv .\data.csv |
    Group-Object OSType |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                OSType        = $_.Name
                AverageUptime = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property AVERAGE_of_Availability -Average).Average
            }
        }
```

This assumes that the CSV is actually comma-separated.  If it's not (as looks the case), then you can try using the `-Delimiter` parameter of `Import-Csv`, or pre-processing the file to make it easier to work with.